# Need To Copy Source Code of CMS Page in Python Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python

I am new to selenium 2.53.6 and Chrome webdriver so I may have overlooked something very simple.  I need to copy the source code of a CMS page in Python 3.3.6 webdriver.

I have tried `page_source` and it doesn't do what I need to have done.  However, I can get the page open in webdriver and it is showing the source code but I haven't been able to select the content and copy it to the clipboard.

I am on a Mac OS X 10.10.5 so I used:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('c').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()
```

But the only thing that happened was I got an "a" and a "c" passed to the page.

I have tried using the context menu of the finder and I can get it to show but can''t get it to select the "select all" option.

```
btn = driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@key='postBody']")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

action = actionChains.context_click(btn).perform()
links = action.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Select All")
links.click()
```

Using the above code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "expertsBrazil2webdriver.py", line 80, in <module>
links = action.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Select All")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

So please tell me a workable approach to get Webdriver to copy the content of the page to the clipboard.

Comment: What do you want to do with the content? And is it from a textarea?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I tried was:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://webscraping.com'  
r = Render(url)  
html = r.frame.toHtml().toUtf8().data()
```

Credit goes to: [WebScraping](https://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/)

Comment: I need to copy the source code that is displayed on the screen only.  Using the url brings all of the cms code and not the content I need.  This is blogger code and they seem to be calling another url for the content I need.  This is evident when I have to use "element7 = driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "postingHtmlBox")))" because it has to be loaded before I can access it by Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of a text area with `get_attribute("value")`

Something like:

```
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@key='postBody']").get_attribute("value")
```

Don't fiddle with trying to use the context menu's or operating system key combinations, this is brittle and the wrong direction to solve most issues.